# Loop until find entry and then use the entry

Tags: files, write

Lets say i have a file which have entries,

File:

```
user pts/1        2016-10-22 19:47 (ip)
user1 pts/2        2016-10-22 20:04 (ip)
user1 pts/3        2016-10-22 20:04 (ip)
```

i want to have a loop until user press number between 1-3 (number of rows in that file)

and when user insert 1 for example i want him the system to send a message to that specific pts (using write user pts/1 command).

Is that even possible somehow? I have no clue where to start.

Comment: Please be more clear in what you're trying to do. You want the user to choose a user to send a message to. You should start by getting to know `while` and `read`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating things.

Here is a short way to ask for a number, and then send a message to that terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

function getNumber()
{
    pattern="[1-3]"
    echo "Enter a number between 1 and 3"

    read number

    if [[ ! "$number" =~ $pattern ]]; then
        echo "Wrong number"
        getNumber
    fi  
}

getNumber

echo "Hello pts$number" > /dev/pts/$number
```

Execution samples below:

```
./pts.sh 
Enter a number between 1 and 3
0
Wrong number
Enter a number between 1 and 3
4
Wrong number
Enter a number between 1 and 3
1
```

Upon correct input (`1` above), I get this output in `/dev/pts/1`:

```
[maulinglawns@ArchLinux slask]$ tty
/dev/pts/1
[maulinglawns@ArchLinux slask]$ Hello pts1
```